# Wifi Password is not getting saved

Tags: 16.04, wireless

Every time I switch my wifi connections from one to another, it keeps asking for the password always. Even if I reboot, I have to enter the passwords for the same wifi connection that I have already used more than once. Does it mean that my wifi connections are not getting saved?